# Dividing a string using regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, string, string-parsing

I have a string like this :

```
"John William Doe 250 / 1000 Adam Smith 500 / 1000 Jane Black 250 / 1000"
```

As you can see, the string consists of people's names and their shares. There can be any number of people (and shares) and people's names can consist of any number of words.

How can I divide this string to three strings like this :

```
"John William Doe 250 / 1000"
"Adam Smith 500 / 1000"
"Jane Black 250 / 1000"
```

I know I need to use regular expression but I couldn't do it myself. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you fixed 3/4 digit fixed for share??

Comment: Is the term 1000 fixed or different?

Comment: @Darshak no it's not fixed, they can be any number of digits

Comment: @shree.pat18 it can be different.

Comment: `([\w\s]*\d*\s\/\s\d*)`

Comment: @bansi  :- wow.. i have checked your expression online..its working perfectly...http://regexstorm.net/tester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not that difficult problem and there's already some answer in comments, I still want to paste code for the OP:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string all = @"John William Doe 250 / 1000 Adam Smith 500 / 1000 Jane Black 250 / 1000";
        Regex r = new Regex(@"(?:\w+\s+)+\d+\s+/\s+\d+");
        foreach (Match m in r.Matches(all))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Is the `@` sign necessary in the example? Thanks

Comment: [String literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`([a-zA-Z ]*)*[0-9]* \/ [0-9]*`

You start with looking for name with a space, and repeating those.

You continue with the number, the slash and the other number

Note the spaces.